# Uploading website to webhost, webconfig Runtime error

Tags: asp.net

I finished my website and uploaded it to my webhost, but i get this error, when trying to access the site (Alternative check it out here: [clematistest.web.surftown.dk](http://clematistest.web.surftown.dk/) ):

> Runtime Error Description: An
>   application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>       <system.web>
>           <customErrors mode="Off"/>
>       </system.web> </configuration>
>
> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's <customErrors>
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.
>
> <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
>
> <configuration>
>       <system.web>
>           <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
>   defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
>       </system.web> </configuration>

i tried to put  in the config file, but i results in the same error.

What should i do to fix this?

/Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this happens if an unhandled exception occurs in the code.

Seeing how you are having problems configuring the web.config to allow the website to show you the error and stack trace remotely,

you could adding TRY and CATCH blocks around parts of the code where you suspect the exception could be thrown...  Then on catch you can do a redirect to a generic simple error page where you can display the exception's message.

**Edit:  you can also try redirecting to a custom error page from the on error event in global.**

Comment: Sounds like an idea. Will look into it when i get home, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the reason of error  in windows events viewer(if it's windows on server and you have access to it). Or to set debug="true" and customErrors mode="Off" in your web.config

Comment: Hmm.. i tried to put in debug = "true" and customErrors but it still gives me the same error. http://www.clematistest.web.surftown.dk Any other suggentions?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message points out, you could turn off custom errors altogether while sorting this out.

In your web.config search for "customErrors" - if you have a fairly default version of the file, this will be commented out completely - remove the comments, and change the custom errors mode from "RemoteOnly" to "Off":

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If there isn't a customErrors block, just add one between the <system.web> tags.

When you've finished, set it back to either "RemoteOnly" or "On", and add at least a defaultRedirect pointing to a friendly error message for your users.

This will then display the full error message, and if you've got a debug build deployed (or you're running a web site and you've set compilation mode to debug rather than a compiled web application) you'll also get line numbers, etc, rather than offsets.

Once you've resolved the issue, I'd recommend following [Roberto Sebestyen's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351242/uploading-website-to-webhost-webconfig-runtime-error/1355255#1355255), and add some proper error handling and reporting to your site ;)